# How to upload multiple images in zen cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, zen-cart

My client is asking for an option to upload multiple images of a product in zen cart admin side, how to do that?

Comment: Please refer this link http://tutorials.zen-cart.com/index.php?article=58

Answer (score 6):

Zen cart module [Image Handler 4 for v1.5.x] for uploading extra/multiple images from admin side

http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1380

Video tutorial for module (How module work?)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGjt-orG7GA